# Why is a default constructor needed here?

Tags: c++, class

I have created a class called Camera that doesn't have a default constructor because I will probably never have to use one. The compiler gives me back an error when I am trying to compile the project:

> C2512: 'Vector3< double >': no appropriate default constructor available

The error is raised at the line of the constructor of the Camera class. Here is my 'camera.h' file:

```
#pragma once

#include "algebra.h"

template <typename T>
class Camera {

public:
    Camera(Vector3<T> position, Vector3<T> direction)
    : m_position(position), m_direction(direction) {
        m_positionNormalized = position.normalize();
        m_directionNormalized = direction.normalize();
    }

private:
    Vector3<T> m_position;
    Vector3<T> m_direction;

    Vector3<T> m_positionNormalized;
    Vector3<T> m_directionNormalized;
};
```

Here is the 'algebra.h' file defining the Vector3 class:

```
#pragma once

#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Vector3 {

public:
    Vector3(T x, T y, T z) : m_x(x), m_y(y), m_z(z) {}

    T norm() const {
        return sqrt(m_x * m_x + m_y * m_y + m_z * m_z);
    }

    Vector3<T> normalize() {
        T m_norm = norm();

        try {
            if (m_norm == 0.)
                throw std::string("Normalization of a zero vector !");
            else {
                m_x /= m_norm;
                m_y /= m_norm;
                m_z /= m_norm;
            }
        }
        catch (std::string const& error) {
            std::cerr << error << std::endl;
        }

        return *this;
    }

private:
    T m_x;
    T m_y;
    T m_z;

};
```

Here is the 'main.cpp' where the constructors are called:

```
#include "camera.h"
#include "algebra.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Vector3<double> position(0., 0., 0.);
    Vector3<double> direction(0., 0., 1.);
    Camera<double> camera(position, direction);

    return 0;
}
```

I agree that there is no default constructor for the Vector3 class, but I don't understand why it is a problem here, since I don't feel like I am calling it.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Are there any other member-variables of type `Vector3` declared in your `Camera` class that are not included in the constructor's initializer-list?

Comment: The cause of the error seems to be in the code you didn't show us.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Vector3 has 3 members-variables that are m_x, m_y and m_z.

Comment: @Balfar your include order is bad because `camera.h` doesn't include `algebra.h` despite depending on it and you're not using include guards. Thus the definition of `Camera` can't figure out what `Vector3` because the name doesn't exist when the compiler parses that. This also explains why I [got it working on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/T847YoMjr)

Comment: @Mgetz true. I did the change but the problem is still here. I have added all the code of my program as DanielLangr has said, the problem should probably come from there.

Comment: It’s m_positionNormalized and m_directionNormalized that require a default constructor since they aren’t in the initialization-list.

Comment: The original close reason may no longer be valid but, in review, I kept this closed because now, it's apparent that the problem is caused by a simple "typo", as pointed out in Jeremy's last comment.